# Assign one model value to another

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a model DropDownConfiguration which is fetching values from database and populating the dropdown list.

Model:

```
public class DropDownConfiguration
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Quarter { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Project { get; set; }
        public string LineID { get; set; }

    }
```

html:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Project", new SelectList(Model.dropConfig, "ID", "Project"), "-- Select Project --", new { required = true, @class = "form-control" })
```

I have another model DetailsConfiguration which has all the fields which need be saved into the database.

```
 public class DetailsConfiguration
    {

        public int Quarter { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Project { get; set; }
        public string ItemModel { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller HttpPost:

```
  [ActionName("DetailsForm")]
        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult DetailsForm(DetailsViewModel model, FormCollection form)
        {

            DetailsConfiguration detailsConfig = new DetailsConfiguration();
            detailsConfig.Quarter = Convert.ToInt32(form["Quarter"]);
            detailsConfig.Year = Convert.ToInt32(form["Year"]);
            detailsConfig.Project = model.detailsConfig.Project;
            detailsConfig.ItemModel = model.detailsConfig.ItemModel;  
            detailsConfig.LineID = model.detailsConfig.LineID;

            floorService.SaveDetails(detailsConfig);

            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.message = "Success";
            return View("DetailsForm");

        }
```

Is there anyway to do something like:

```
model.detailsConfig.Project = model.dropConfig.Project
```

I need the selection of Project to be posted back to database through DetailsConfiguration.

Comment: Well, you want to tell the first one is viewmodel and the second one is data model, right? You can have both data model & viewmodel in same project, also able to assign data model from viewmodel properties.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yeah . how can we assign like i have mentioned above?

Comment: Create a new `DetailsConfiguration` instance (`model.detailsConfig = new DetailsConfiguration()` and assign existing `DropDownConfiguration` in `model.dropConfig` instance to that - it's the key point.

Comment: can you elaborate? your solution is unclear to me sorry

Comment: You can create a new `DetailsConfiguration` with the properties values of `DropDownConfiguration`. See my answer below..

Comment: I don't know what `model.detailsConfig` and `model.dropConfig` belongs to - you can do such like `model.detailsConfig = new DetailsConfiguration(); model.detailsConfig.Project = model.dropConfig.Project` if `model` belongs to a single parent viewmodel.

Comment: detailsConfig belongs to DetailsConfiguration, dropConfig belongs to DropConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

You could create a mapper which sets the values of the properties in `DropDownConfiguration` to `DetailsConfiguration`.

When you change the dropdown you send the selected `DropDownConfiguration` to the server. You know exactly what properties you can expect here so you can do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult AddDetailsConfiguration(DropDownConfiguration parameter)
{
   //check here if values in parameter are set

   var detailsConfiguration = new DetailsConfiguration {
        Quarter = parameter.Quarter,
        Year = parameter.Year,
        Project = parameter.Project
   }

   //Insert detailsConfiguration to database

   Return Ok();
}
```

Note that you have to make sure you send a DropDownConfiguration object on selecting a dropdown item. You could also only send the values you need like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult AddDetailsConfiguration(int quarter, int year, string project)
{
    //Check here if values in parameter are set and if values are correct

    var detailsConfiguration = new DetailsConfiguration
    {
         Quarter = quarter,
         Year = year,
         Project = project
    }

    //Insert detailsConfiguration to database

    Return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I have a separate httppost which has all the fields from details config.  I will update that above. Please have a look at updated question

Comment: my code crashes at   `defaultDB.AddInParameter(dbCmd, "Project", System.Data.DbType.String, detailsConfig.Project);`   where it doesn't allow null values. This code is a part of   `Repository`   section. Anyway I had posted the controller code to check with you if we can merge AddDetailsConfiguration with ActionResult DetailsForm

Comment: I think your your `model.detailsConfig.Project` has a null value when you enter your POST method. You should check if the value is null and when it is you should make it `string.Empty` because your database probably doesnt allow null values for the column project.

Comment: Its null because what value i am selecting from Project dropdown (dropConfig) is not taken into detailsConfig

Comment: So the problem now is that you don't get all the values in the parameter `DetailsViewModel model` that you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158944/discussion-between-shrey-pav-and-salvatore-lucky-luciano).